# Nexus S - access\modify drivers

Tags: android, linux, driver, device-driver

I am developing with the Nexus S, and would like to know if there is a way I can access\modify the drivers on this device? I may be looking into building my own device, however if there is a way I can use an existing phone first to try this out would be helpful.

Comment: Don't know why people are voting to close; operating system programming is still programming, as opposed to configuration tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a non-hack official method by which you can unlock the Nexus S bootloader to install your own build from AOSP sources, or from one of the community-developed roms.

I'd suggest installing something built from unmodified sources to verify that you have the process down before you change anything.  You will also want that as a snapshot to go back to if your break something in your changes.

You may not need to replace the entire ROM; depending on what you want to change you might be able to just install a custom kernel and/or add some loadable modules and change a few related startup scripts using root access (which you would presumably achieve somewhere along the way).

Comment: Thank-you for your help! Any ideas where I can find this official method? I have already build AOSP source and flashed it onto the phone. Now I just need a way to tinker with some of the drivers.

Comment: If you've built and flashed AOSP source, then you don't need to ask about the official bootloader unlock.  Modifying the drivers would be normal linux driver work.  As a suggestion, focus on the specific problem you want to solve and find the related code in the kernel (or in some cases, android platform) source.  There are worse ideas than blind recursive grepping...

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing the only way to access the kernel is via http://android.git.kernel.org ? (As Todd B has posted in his answer)

Comment: No, there are many android kernel trees floating around - that's just the official AOSP one but others would include vendor trees and community rom kernel trees, though it's possible that's the most appropriate.  Did you build one in your AOSP build or did you only build userspace code?  Again, I would urge you to concentrate on the desired functionality - someone may even already have a version with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Google and Samsung made the kernel for the Nexus S available a while back: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung

Not sure what exactly you're looking for, but the drivers directory should get you started.